# C FIFO's - How to read server's stdin while waiting for client requests

Tags: c, linux, fifo

I'm implementing a simple ipc system using linux named pipes in C.

I have this server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "external/paths.h"
#include "external/sv.h"
#include "external/tags.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, bytes_read;
    char request[200];

    // create fifo
    mknod(FIFO_SERVER, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

    puts("Servidor initialized.\nWaiting for client requests.");

    // open created fifo
    fd = open(FIFO_SERVER, O_RDONLY);

    while(1)
    {
        if( (bytes_read = read(fd, request, LEN_CL_REQUEST)) == -1 )
            perror("error read()");

        if(bytes_read == 0)
            continue;

        if(bytes_read > 0)
        {
            printf("Request read: %s\n", request);
            // answer back
        }
    } 

    close(fd);
    unlink(FIFO_SERVER);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm ommiting the client because my question is only related with the server. The communication is working fine, I can read requests from the client and I can answer them. Now, lets say I want to, at anytime, be able to quit the server when the key 'Q' is pressed.. I can't do this because my code blocks on the `read` statement waiting for another client request, so I have no way to read the `stdin`..

Is something like this possible to do? I'm thinking in something like non-blocking the `read` statement and try to read `stdin` for a few seconds, then check again for incoming requests.. I've been searching but I haven't found anything similar.

**UPDATE**:

I followed Jean-Baptiste Yunès approach but it turns out that `select` is only detecting the fifo events, I don't really know why.

This is the code I'm testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int result, fd, maxDescriptor;
    char input[20], texto[100];

    mknod("fifo", S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
    fd = open("fifo", O_RDWR); // RDWR to avoid EOF return to select

    fd_set readset;
    FD_ZERO(&readset);
    FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &readset);
    FD_SET(fd, &readset);

    maxDescriptor = fileno(stdin) > fd ? fileno(stdin) : fd;

    while(1)
    {
        result = select(maxDescriptor+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if(result == -1)
            perror("select()");
        else if(result)
        {
            puts("data available.");

            if( FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &readset) )
            {
                scanf("%s", input);
                printf("%s\n", input);

                if( strcmp(input, "Q") == 0 )
                    break;
            }

            if( FD_ISSET(fd, &readset) )
            {
                read(fd, texto, 100);
                printf("lido:\n%s\n", texto);
            }
        }
        else
            puts("no data.");
    }

    unlink("fifo");
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As Jean-Baptiste Yunès pointed out, there's need to reset fd_set since it doesn't reset automatically.

Here's the final working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int result, fd, maxDescriptor;
    char input[20], texto[100];

    mknod("fifo", S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
    fd = open("fifo", O_RDWR); // RDWR to avoid EOF return to select

    fd_set readset;
    FD_ZERO(&readset);
    FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &readset);
    FD_SET(fd, &readset);

    maxDescriptor = fileno(stdin) > fd ? fileno(stdin) : fd;

    while(1)
    {
        result = select(maxDescriptor+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if(result == -1)
            perror("select()");
        else if(result)
        {
            puts("data available.");

            if( FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &readset) )
            {
                scanf("%s", input);
                printf("%s\n", input);

                if( strcmp(input, "Q") == 0 )
                    break;
                }

            if( FD_ISSET(fd, &readset) )
            {
                read(fd, texto, 100);
                printf("lido:\n%s\n", texto);
            }

            FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &readset);
            FD_SET(fd, &readset);
        }
        else
            puts("no data.");
    }

    unlink("fifo");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: select or poll will let you block waiting on multiple file descriptors and unblock when any of them is ready for read or write (lookup select)

Comment: You can also consider writing your code with asynchronous I/O. "libevent" is a nice c library that simplify writing asynchronous code.

Comment: Servers mostly run services indefinitely and do not read input from stdin. They only read a communication channel and are either started or stopped (killed) from scripts.

Comment: For standard situations like killing a server a common way is to install a signal handler for SIGINT and SIGTERM, which shuts down the process in a clean way. The SIGINT handler is usually called on ^C on the terminal, while SIGTERM is used by start/stop-scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `select`. You need to wait on both channels: something from the pipe or something from stdin but you never know which one to read. The purpose of select is to make your process wait on any channel for read or write.

```
fd_set readset;
FD_ZERO(&readset);        // empty set of descriptor to select on
FD_SET(fd, &readset);     // add the pipe
FD_SET(stdin, &readset);  // add stdin
result = select(fd + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL); // now wait for something to read on at least one channel (pipe or stdin)
if (result>0) {
    if (FD_ISSET(fd, &readset)) { // test for pipe availability
        // now read the pipe
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(stdin, &readset)) { // test for stdin availability
        // now read stdin
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. One question, what's that socket_fd argument you pass to select? Shouldn't it be fd+1 ?

Comment: Thanks.. However, I've just tested out this approach and select is only detecting the fifo events.. Could you please check my question edit?
Also, I've used the function `fileno` to get `stdin`'s integer descriptor since passing `stdin` to `FD_SET` and `FD_ISSET` was triggering an error.

Comment: @BrunoCasteleiro: You have to reset the `fd_set` in the loop. It doesn't reset itself (or use `poll`, which keeps its request and output separate). `stdin` likely gets cleared the first time and remains cleared afterwards.

Comment: Hm... I never though no-reseting would be the problem since `select` was continuously read my client requests without any type of reset. I guess `stdin` really gets cleared. Thanks a lot, its working :)

Comment: Also be careful that stdin may be buffered and availability of keys to process conditional to buffer validation.